# Website traffic suddenly dropped by 90%

Tags: seo, google, traffic

Our yellowpages website `lokaterr.com` was getting good traffic,but suddenly traffic got reduced to 90%  since may 3rd. There are no warnings or errors in Google Webmaster tools. Please help me out how to understand this issue.
[image]

Comment: I actually think such questions can provide value to the community, not sure why it had to be closed. I for one am interested in the possible reasons, and ways to investigate. There are many things that are best learned through an example.

Comment: @Noam, I sort of agree with you, but he didn't provide enough details to keep this from being a back and forth troubleshooting affair. (Didn't vote either way)

Comment: @JMC I assume he wasn't sure what else he should include and he did give the domain name (which btw a simple google query doesn't show) and date. Depends on the case, but might even be enough. I get it that this can't be too much of a back and forth troubleshooting affair, but it's quite clear the most popular use case of SE is to solve your own problems. Glad at-least I'm not alone with this feeling :)

Comment: The question can be modified to ask if there are any Google algorithm changes/penalties, and so forth that happened recently that they could be looking for. If that is the question, I say no. Look to linking. It seems there was a sweep about this time that focused on linking schemes though this is business as usual for and not a change. Google applies some portions of it's algorithms in batches from time to time. Part of this is to apply new tolerances to existing algorithms or just a periodical sweep. This often coincides with a refresh of the indexes that may have been happening more lately.

Comment: Not sure how you were looking - *(which btw a simple google query doesn't show)* - but I did a site: and found 232k pages. It may be that you are hitting another data center? If that is the case, then perhaps that is the answer or part of it. I visited the site but did not dig around and it looks fairly clean. I forget how, but there is a way to check the various Google data centers. It may help to indicate a specif issue. I have no idea otherwise. Again, check linking too.

Comment: How old is the site? For how long have you been getting "good traffic"?

Comment: Lots of threads already on the site regarding drop in traffic and it'd be more benefit to the community that users leave answers, edit, and improve existing questions and answers already on the site. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=traffic%20drop%20is%3aquestion